# What can i do to make a http put request from springboot to a URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to make a http put request to elastic search server, running on port 9200, to set its mappings initially when the index is created, explicitly, I want to do this via spring boot and not via curl. The put request should have a body, of JSON format, which contains attributes of the mappings.

Comment: Have a look on org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate, it's a high level REST interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

Here is how i have tried to do it, for testing i made simple get api which create a index and updates it afterwards.

```java
@GetMapping
    public Map<String, Object> updateEsMapping() throws JsonProcessingException {
        //Create mapping index
        final Map<String, Object> request =
                Map.of("properties", Map.of(
                        "id", Map.of("type", "keyword"),
                        "name", Map.of("type", "keyword"),
                        "date", Map.of("type", "date")
                ));
        //Compose  json header
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        //Create entity
        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request), headers);

        //es constants
        final String host = "http://localhost:9200/";
        final String indexName = "raw-sample-document-creation/";
        final String mapping = "_mapping/";

        //First create index
        restTemplate.put(host + indexName, null);

        //Update mapping
        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(host + indexName + mapping, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
        
        
        return Map.of("status", "ok", "request", exchange.getBody()
                .replace("\n", "")
                .replace("\r", "")
        );
    }
```

You can explore more here for standard approach
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients